# Wordpress image gallery width open a link

Tags: wordpress

I looking for wordpress images gallery hack, plugin, etc. for loading images without standing into post or page.

For example

```
<img src="test.jpg" /><a href="link to big gallery images">Show all gallery</a>
```

Each post or page needs a image gallery.

Show all gallery needs to be outside the page, post, becouse, if I load a page, with hidden images that are in post or page, the pages comes load very long.

Image gallery needs to be like fancybox example, open gallery link, and browse images with next and prev buttons.

is there any way, method to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried here?  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ 
Do you need to do this programmatically, or would an image gallery plug-in work?  For example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/